# What narayana guru and Chattampi Swamikal tells about Adi shankaracharya?

Tags: advaita, adi-shankaracharya

The great scholars like narayana guru and Chattampi Swamikal tells about Adi shankaracharya and what the scholars tells about Shankara in book vedadhikara niroopanam(Malayalam book)?